# How to create a text area where users can write and publish?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to ask if can anybody help me to create a text area where users can write down (for journalling) whatever they like and then publish it using javascript, HTML, and CSS no more.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: use the `<textarea>` tag. However it will not be sufficient to be able to post somethign on a website. This would require a server sided language as PHP. HTML, CSS and JS are run client sided. As such they wont be able to post something on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text area with this In html

```
<textarea id="myTextarea"> </textarea>
```

And in JavaScript with the following code you can get the text area value

```
var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
```

And now using back end languages you can store the information of the variable x in the database and so on.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry but your question is too generic. You can find lots of HTML textarea examples on the internet, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) is a great example to implement a textarea.
Styling using CSS is up to you how you want to style it. Publishing the text would be more tricky because you need to answer the question of where do I post the info to? (this will regard backend development, databases, email, domain, and maybe more).

Comment: You dont need a lot of backend development to just post something. You also dont need a database email, nor a domain. A webserver is always reachable through its IP. no domain required for it. E-Mail has nothing to do with it. A database such as MySQL is certainly helpfull but also not required. You can store it simply in a simple textfile aswell. What you actually need is a server sided language such as PHP. HTML, CSS and JS are run client sided and as such cant manipulate information on the server.